# Do two new special points in any triangle exist?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

There are some special points in any triangle, as [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point), [symmedian point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmedian#Symmedian_point), [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter), [Morley center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley_centers), et cetera.

> > Let $P$ be a point on the plane, $PA$, $PB$, $PC$ meet $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ respectively. From my construction by [geogebra sofware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra). I proposed a conjecture:
> >
> > *In any triangle exist two points $P$ so that: $AA'=BB'=CC'$.*
> >
> > **My question:** Is the conjecture above correct?

[image]

**My geogebra:**

The Red locus: If $P$ lie on red locus then $AA'=CC'$.

The Blue locus: If $P$ lie on red locus then $AA'=BB'$.

The Pink locus: If $P$ lie on pink locus then $CC'=BB'$

**See also:**

- [Triangle centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/tcenters/index.html)

Comment: For equilateral triangle the number of such points is not 2 for sure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your conjecture is true: these two points are sometimes called the equicevian points of $ABC.$

Comment: Thank You very much, this is new point. I have never seen the point before: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287121316_Equicevian_Points_of_a_Triangle

Comment: Oh no, This is old points http://www.anubih.ba/Journals/vol.11,no-1,y15/08Rev-Volenec-Kolar.pdf

Answer (score 8):

These two points are the focuses of Steiner circumconic https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_ellipse.

Comment: Since a Google search for "Steiner circumconic" didn't return too convincing results, why not add its definition?